# Azure function - VS2017 Tooling - Missing binding in function.json

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I created a simple HttpTrigger Azure function using VS 17 15.3 (with the nuget package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.2) with the wizard. It gave me the following code:

```cs
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string name, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

When I run the function in debug mode with VS and calling it with Postman, it's working fine, I have the body response.

When I start the same function, using the CLI: func host start and calling it with post man, the function doesnt return the body. I have an Http 200 with an empty content. :(

I found, that in the generated `function.json`, there is no http out binding. My generated `function.json`

```json
{ 
    "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.0.0", 
    "configurationSource": "attributes", 
    "bindings": [ 
        { 
            "type": "httpTrigger", 
            "route": "HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}", 
            "methods": [ "get", "post" ], 
            "authLevel": "anonymous", 
            "name": "req" 
        } 
    ], 
    "disabled": false, 
    "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\FunctionApp1.dll", 
    "entryPoint": "FunctionApp1.Function1.Run" 
}
```

When I add the http out binding, It's working fine using func host start

```json
{ 
    "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.0.0", 
    "configurationSource": "attributes", 
    "bindings": [ 
        { 
            "type": "httpTrigger", 
            "route": "HttpTriggerCSharp/name/{name}", 
            "methods": [ "get", "post" ], 
            "authLevel": "anonymous", "name": "req" 
        }, 
        { 
            "type": "http", 
            "direction": "out", 
            "name": "res" 
        } 
    ], 
    "disabled": false, 
    "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\FunctionApp1.dll", 
    "entryPoint": "FunctionApp1.Function1.Run" 
}
```

It's very strange that in debug mode, it's work and not using cli directly...

Thanks for your help

Comment: make sure you're using the latest version of the CLI (1.0.2)

Answer (score 1):

> When I start the same function, using the CLI: func host start and calling it with post man, the function doesnt return the body. I have an Http 200 with an empty content

I create a httpTrigger Azure functions app, and I can get response body when run it in debug mode.

If I use the CLI `func host start` to run function, I can also get response body as expected.

[image]

***Request &Response***

[image]

Besides, based on my test (removing http out binding), if http out binding is missing in function.json, which will case empty content in response body.

***Note***: the issue can not be reproduced on my side (*Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Preview (3) Version 15.3.0 Preview 7.0*). But for this issue, as you did, manually adding http out binding would be a workaround to solve the issue. Besides, if possible, you can post a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues) and include the title “CLI:”.